# Perlin Noise for iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, xcode, opengl-es, ios5

How can i get a sand effect in perlin-noise ? Do somebody have any tutorial to implement perlin noise in iPhone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really straightforward.

Objective-C is a superset of C so just take original source code (that can be found [here](http://mrl.nyu.edu/~perlin/doc/oscar.html#noise)), save it in a `.c` (this is not a requirement) and use it. You will have to understand how perlin noise works to be able to correctly tweak parameters but I personally did it and it worked great.